# How to position text vertically beside image depending on image size?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

How can I position text vertically beside an image next to its bottom right corner? The image is always centered but it isn't always the same size, it can have different width and height.
Example of what I am trying to accomplish [image]

Here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ivan-topi/pen/MWemNew)

```css
.featuredimg {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px; 
}

.author {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: rotate(90deg) translate(-50%,-100%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="featuredimg">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/550">
  <div class="author">Author: Asadfasdfasdf</div>
</div>

<div class="featuredimg">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/850">
  <div class="author">Author: Asadfasdfasdf</div>
</div>

<div class="featuredimg">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1250">
  <div class="author">Author: Asadfasdfasdf</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply `display: inline-block` to the image/s and use `transform-origin: bottom right` on the rotated element which contains the text. You can use the `bottom` parameter in  `.author` to fine-tune the exaxt vertical position of the text.

```css
.featuredimg {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px; 
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.author {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 4px;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: bottom right;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="featuredimg">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/550">
  <div class="author">Author: Asadfasdfasdf</div>
</div>

<div class="featuredimg">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/850">
  <div class="author">Author: Asadfasdfasdf</div>
</div>

<div class="featuredimg">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1250">
  <div class="author">Author: Asadfasdfasdf</div>
</div>
```